# Can't hibernate on Lubuntu 18.10

Tags: lubuntu, 18.10

Actually I'm having issues when trying to hibernate on my computer, it does nothing after I try to hibernate using Lubuntu 18.10

```
lxqt-leave --hibernate

 (0x7ffd4d782c90) Warning: Icon theme "breeze" not found.
 (0x7ffd4d782c90) Debug: systemd: "CanHibernate" = "no"
 (0x7ffd4d782c90) Warning: ** Dbus error **************************
 (0x7ffd4d782c90) Warning: Error name  "org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs"
 (0x7ffd4d782c90) Warning: Error msg   "No such interface “org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties”"
 (0x7ffd4d782c90) Warning: ****************************************
 (0x7ffd4d782c90) Warning: dbusCall: QDBusInterface is invalid "org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit" "/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager" "org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager" "CanHibernate"


echo $?
0
```

I know it's a recent Ubuntu distro and probably that's why I found nothing related that would be solve tha problem, I just found [an issue](https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt/issues/1282) on lxqt github talking about that.

Have you some workaround for that situation?

Comment: do you have a swap space?

Comment: @cipricus Yes I do, I found a solution, looks like after Ubuntu 16 you have to specify the swap partition uuid on kernel params [reference](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1769297)

Comment: would you please post that as answer?

Answer (score 3):

Got the same problem.

Don't know if this helps, for me this works:

```
sudo systemctl hibernate
```

Answer (score 2):

After some researching I found that after Ubuntu 18 it's required to configure UUID on kernel initialization to get hibernation to work

Find your swap partition UUID

```
$ cat /etc/fstab  | grep swap
# swap was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=d68dc416-6d9a-4f29-8d9d-fabb3f9d8a72 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Then update kernel init params with swap UUID, something like below

```
$ cat /etc/default/grub 
...
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=d68dc416-6d9a-4f29-8d9d-fabb3f9d8a72"
...
```

Last step is to update grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

[More details](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1769297)