# Which is the most Energy efficient Ubuntu flavour?

Tags: power-management, battery, hibernate

I've been using Ubuntu for over a year now and now with my new XPS13 (9370) I've been very disappointed by the battery life (or having to manually lock CPU frequency) or the lack of (out of the box) hibernation.

Which Ubuntu flavours are the most energy efficient and have a hibernation feature out of the box?

Comment: Ubuntu welcomes your contributions to improve battery life, energy efficiency, and hibernation compatibility. Ubuntu improves through the software and support contributions of volunteers.

Comment: Install `laptop-mode-tools` and it will'be much more effective ;-) Ubuntu flavors muxt be almost same.

Comment: @Pilot6 Unfortunatelly Ubuntu flavors are not the same...

Comment: Some of Ubuntu flavors run a lot of python scripts in background (like gnome plugins or budgie services) and python consumes extra juice, much more than compiled code running in background.

Comment: Energy Efficiency is not just the OS at play - it's also the system hardware.  If your system pulls more power at base regardless of the OS, that's part of efficiency as well

Answer (score 1):

There are a few power efficiency benchmarks, but I'll recommend [Benchmarked: The Most Power-Efficient Ubuntu 19.04 Flavor Will Surprise You](https://www.forbes.com/sites/jasonevangelho/2019/05/06/benchmarked-the-most-power-efficient-ubuntu-19-04-flavor-will-surprise-you)

TLDR; Ubuntu Mate is activelly optimized for low power consumption.

Answer (score 0):

I guess Lubuntu (LXQt) or Xubuntu (XFCE) use much less resources.
Hibernation should work with swap enabled.

Answer (score 0):

My personally preference is [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.me/), which as PAPPL said uses the LXQt desktop environment.  I've used Lubuntu relatively smoothly on a quarter GB of memory...  It also doesn't have a lot of additional graphic effects, which improves battery usage.  Hibernation isn't enabled by default, but [according to this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089587/cant-hibernate-on-lubuntu-18-10) it's not hard to enable it.

XFCE could be an option too, but my personal experience has been that it's not that much better than Gnome or Unity; it's maybe a bit better on battery usage, but it's not that impressive.  Also, you'll probably [also have the issue with hibernation](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1769297).

Another option which I have nearly no experience with is [Ubuntu Budgie](https://ubuntubudgie.org/): I really can't speak as an authority having only used it a few times, but it appears to be quite light - perhaps comparable to Lubuntu.

The thing that I can't recommend enough is that you install [TLP](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2018/11/18/quick-tip-improve-battery-life-ubuntu-18-04-higher/); in some cases it can make a huge difference, whatever flavor you're using.