Hibernate from command line works, but not from menu
I have recently installed Lubuntu 24.04 on an old Dell laptop (it was previously running Windows 7!). I have followed instructions to enable hibernate, and
sudo systemctl hibernate

works just fine. I have a "hibernate" button on the menu too - but it doesn't actually do anything.  Specifically, it doesn't enter a hibernate state (as opposed to another question where it didn't resume).
Any suggestions what I have done wrong?  (Or more plausibly, what more debugging information you need?)
Edit:  Running lxqt-leave is much more informative:
$ lxqt-leave --hibernate
systemd: "CanHibernate" = "no"
** Dbus error **************************
Error name  "org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs"
Error msg   "No such interface “org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties”"
****************************************
dbusCall: QDBusInterface is invalid 
   "org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit" 
   "/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager"
   "org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager" "CanHibernate"

(The last four lines are actually a single line which I have wrapped for readability).
Searching for that error message, finds https://askubuntu.com/a/1097779/ - but I don't have a swap partition I have a swap file.  Do I just retain the "offset" parameter, but replace the device with the UUID?

I don't know, but your menu is using lxqt-leave --hibernate doesn't work I believe; I wonder what you'd get if you tried that (hoping it'll provide a little more detail; the command you used at terminal directs the linux kernel to shutdown, not your GUI)

@user68186 Except that the basic hibernate functionality is working (see my point about systemctl hibernate working. ... and following through to the linked FAQ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq, it doesn't say "you can't hibernate to a swap file".  It may be easier to repartition the disk and add a swap partition though...

Yes, it may be easier to create a partition. I wish you the best and hope you find a swap file based solution.

So the important point is that "QDBusInterface is invalid" means that you have your configuration files wrong.
There are two ways of enabling hibernate for lxqt-leave.  The recommended way for 24.04 is to create /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/10-enable-hibernate.rules with the following content.
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.handle-hibernate-key" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-ignore-inhibit")
    {
        return polkit.Result.YES;
    }
});

Earlier versions of Ubuntu needed one to create /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla with the following content:
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.handle-hibernate-key;org.freedesktop.login1;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-ignore-inhibit
ResultActive=yes

I am not sure if the .pkla file will work on 24.04.  What certainly doesn't work is creating the .pkla file with the .rules content.  (No prizes for guessing how I know that.)
Incidentally, contrary to other advice on the web, my Ubuntu Mate 24.04 hibernates fine with partitions identified as /dev/xxxx - you don't need to use UUIDs (although I haven't confirmed that with lubuntu).  Also, I suspect a swap file will work too - again, I can't confirm because I switched to a swap partition.
